# In Perl you use brackets to extract your matches what is the equivalent of that in c#

Tags: c#, regex, perl

For instance in Perl I can do 
`$x=~/$(\d+)\s/` which is basically saying from variable x find any number preceded by $ sign and followed by any white space character. Now $1 is equal to the number. 
In C# I tried

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"$(\d+)\s");

    if (regex.IsMatch(text))
    {
        // need to access matched number here?
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, your regex there `$(\d+)\s` actually means: *find a number after the end of the string*. It can never match. You have to escape the `$` since it's a metacharacter.

Anyway, the equivalent C# for this is:

```
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"\$(\d+)\s");
if (match.Success)
{
    var number = match.Groups[1].Value;
    // ...
}
```

And, for better maintainability, groups can be named:

```
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"\$(?<number>\d+)\s");
if (match.Success)
{
    var number = match.Groups["number"].Value;
    // ...
}
```

And in this particular case you don't even have to use groups in the first place:

```
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"(?<=\$)\d+(?=\s)");
if (match.Success)
{
    var number = match.Value;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucas I totally forgot about the $ sign. Yes I knew it was end of string in regex. It just never crossed my mind when i was dealing with money sign.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Match` method instead of `IsMatch` and you need to escape `$` to match it literally because it is a character of special meaning meaning "end of string".

```
Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"\$(\d+)\s");
if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a matched result, use `Match` instead of `IsMatch`.

```
var regex = new Regex("^[^@]*@(?<domain>.*)$"); 
// accessible via 
regex.Match("foo@domain.com").Groups["domain"]
// or use an index
regex.Match("foo@domain.com").Matches[0]
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj, The regex I supplied was just an example of pulling the domain out of an email address.  (Not that I recommend using it, since email parsing is a rather difficult thing to get right - but it works as an example)

Comment: how an unescaped dollor symbol would match the literal dollar symbol?

Comment: provide the answer regarding this question only, it would confuse the future readers. I think you mean this `^[^$]*$(.*)$` . But this is wrong, because there is no unescaped `$` symbol. And this won't met `find any number preceded by $ sign and followed by any white space character.` condition.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I did not address his regex in any way.  He did not ask how to extract a number after a dollar sign, he asked for the C# way to access the value of a matched group.  If I have to find dollar amounts, I would use `\$(?<amount>\s*\d+(\.\d+)?)`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, No, if he want's help on the specific regex, he should post a specific question requesting it.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts.  I am unconcerned with the correctness of his regex, since he seems familiar with perl regex and will presumably understand the error he's made.  He asked for help on getting a matched value in C#.